# Android-Not able to parse and add rss feeds from multiple sites to one object

Tags: android, rss, feed, rss-reader

I am trying to add rss from multiple sites like following

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    List<RssItem> rssItems = null;
    List<RssItem> rssItems1=null;
    List<RssItem> listfinal=null;
    try {
        RssParser parser = new RssParser();

     rssItems=parser.parse(getInputStream(LINK_FIRST);
     rssItems = parser.parse(getInputStream(LINK_SECOND));
             listfinal.addAll(rssItems);
             listfinal.addAll(rssItems1);

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.w(e.getMessage(),e);
    }

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) listfinal);
    ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
    receiver.send(0, bundle);
}
```

But I am not able to get the feeds from these two sites and add these all on listfinal object.

If I am adding only rssItems or rssItems1 in the bundle,then it is working fine.

I have searched but have not got any solution for this problem.
Please help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I have got the answer. First I have add one item to rssItem list
Next I have add next items to rssItem1 and 
rssItem=addAll(rssItem1);

:)